# How to set default value on Select2 Autocomplete via hook_alter

Tags: 8, forms

What's the best way to set a default value to a Select2 autocomplete field widget on form load (I'm using a reference view to populate options). I've tried a ton of different variations from within form_alter with no success, such as...

```
$form['field_name']['widget']['#select2']['id'] = 12
```

I can set the hidden `<select>` element with...

```
$form['field_name']['widget']['#default_value'] = 12
```

...but this value doesn't populate into the Select2 Widget.

I've combed through docs and issues without finding a solution. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the select2 widget the ***#default_value'*** is an array so try with

```
 $form['field_name']['widget']['#default_value'] = [12];
```

It will work!

Comment: I appreciate the response. Unfortunately as i mentioned above, this only populates the hidden <select> element and not the actual Select2 Autocomplete field. Any other tips?!?!

Comment: i have tested it on select2 widget what you mentioned above is only 12 as integer not array *[12]* as it in my answer add **[]** it will work

Comment: Thank you for the reply - you are totally correct. I added some custom code previous to render the dropdown's HTML... and that messed things up. My bad ;)

Comment: you are welcome, i'm glad that helped